# How do you convert format/va_list to std::string? (How do you use vsnprintf/_s?)

Tags: c++, c++17

Suppose a third-party library has a logging callback with a signature of:

```
using LogCallback = void (*)(const char* fmt, va_list ap);
```

and you need to provide a callback that passes the log message to a function that requires a `std::string`:

```
void PrintLogMessage(const std::string& message);
```

I assume you need to use one of the vsprintf family of functions:

```
std::string VaList2String(const char* fmt, va_list ap) {
   /* ??? something with vnsprintf or vnsprintf_s ??? */
}

void MyLogCallback(const char* fmt, va_list ap) {
    std::string message = VaList2String(format, ap);
    PrintLogMessage(message);   
}
```

What is the correct (portable and secure) way to implement `VaList2String` in the above that is compatible with all the major platforms/implementations?

Comment: Use [`vsprintf()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vsprintf/) to format it into a C string, then convert that to a `std::string`.

Comment: @Barmar: How big of a buffer do I need to allocate to pass to vsprintf ?

Comment: There's no way to know. You can use `vsnprintf()`  so you can tell it how big the buffer is. You can use the return value to tell if it was big enough. If not, you repeat with a bigger buffer.

Comment: That's something that only you can figure out, since only you would know what would be the largest possible log message, and use `vsnprintf` in order to guard against buffer overflows.

Comment: You can do it in a loop, trying larger buffers until it succeeds.

Comment: In order to call `vsnprintf` more than once do I need to use `va_start`, `va_end` and/or `va_copy` ?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos if you want to use a `va_list` for multiple iterations, you have to use `va_copy()`. As for the buffer size, some implementations allow you to pass in a NULL buffer pointer to query the necessary buffer size. Some implementations provide a separate function for that purpose.

Answer (score 4):

```
void MyLogCallback(const char* fmt, va_list ap) {
    std::string message;
    va_list ap_copy;
    va_copy(ap_copy, ap);
    size_t len = vsnprintf(0, 0, fmt, ap_copy);
    message.resize(len + 1);  // need space for NUL
    vsnprintf(&message[0], len + 1,fmt, ap);
    message.resize(len);  // remove the NUL
    PrintLogMessage(message);
}
```

A `va_list` is commonly actually an array under the hood, so the `ap` being passed in as an argument is really a pointer.  We need `va_copy` to make a copy of the pointed at va_list so we can traverse it twice.

Note that you could probably get away without the + 1 in the (first) resize and then would not need the second resize at all, but it would technically be undefined behavior as you're violating std::string's constraints by overwriting the terminal NUL that it maintains with another NUL.

Comment: A `std::string` has a NUL at one past the end, so do you need the `+1`?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos: yes, because vsnprintf wants to write the NUL and you can't (legally) overwrite the std::string's NUL with another NUL even though that would probably not cause a problem.

Comment: @ChrisDodd "*you can't (legally) overwrite the std::string's NUL with another NUL*" - since C++11, you legally can.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: The resolution of [LWG2475](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2475) makes overwriting the NUL terminator with NUL well-defined.